# Django Rest - Serializer: must be a instance on create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create create a nested serializer using the Django Rest framework. The relationship is Profile X User but when i use `Profile.objects.create(user=profile, **user_data)` i get `ValueError: Cannot assign "<Profile: Profile object (7)>": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.`.

This should be some rookie misunderstanding of models relationship definitions or the serializer declaration itself but I can't find anything around the docs. If someone can point me a direction I'll be gracefull.

**models.py**

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp']

class Profile(models.Model):

    # choices [...]

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    profile_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=PROFILE_CHOICES,default=TEAMMEMBER)
    authentication_token  = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=True)
    avatar_url  = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    permissions = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default= timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['timestamp']
```

**serializer.py**

```py
class UserSerlializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'password']

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerlializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'profile_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=profile, **user_data)
        return Profile
```

**POST**

```
{   
    "profile_type" : "ST",
      "user": {
        "name" : "test",
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "password" : "123456"
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is here. `Profile.objects.create(user=profile, **user_data)`. You are assigning `profile` object to the `Profile.user`. It must be a `User` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating instances in *wrong* way. Change your **`create(...)`** method as,

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerlializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'profile_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_instance = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        profile_instance = Profile.objects.create(user=user_instance, **validated_data)
        return profile_instance
```

Comment: I was about to add this answer to save 1 query, but I will leave it as it is. This is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Profile.user` should be`User` instance, but you are assigning `Profile` instance.

Change your `create` method to this:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerlializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'profile_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data) # 1. creating user
        profile.user = user # 2. assigning user
        profile.save()  # 3. saving profile after adding user
        return profile # returning Profile instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

inherit your user model from django contrib auth module also, and make a one to one relation with profile

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```